# Correspondence analysis vs chi square

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, correspondence-analysis

My data:

```
df=structure(list(A = c(33.9166666666667, 5.16666666666667, 29.9166666666667
), B = c(12.6666666666667, 3.16666666666667, 20.6666666666667
), D = c(106.416666666667, 26.1666666666667, 196.416666666667
)), .Names = c("A", "B", "D"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
3L))
```

People will buy two products and for each product for one or several reasons. For product 1 (reason=1,2,3) and product 2 (reason=A,B,D) and the reasons could be combinated. I obtained this table by ponderate the reasons, gives it weight and make addition finally of all matrix. My aims was to explore if there is association between resaons, so I used CA.

I used the following R code :

```
#install.packages("FactoMineR")
library(FactoMineR)
CA(df)
```

[image]

My interpretations of the AFC : 
1- The first Axis oppose modalities 3 and 1, and the modalities D and A.
2- Customer who buy product 1 for the reason 3 tends to buy product 2 for the reason D.
3- Customer who buy product 2 for the reason 1 tends to buy product 2 for the reason A.

Now what is strange is when I execute a `chisq.test(df)`, I'm failing to reject the null hypothesis (Reasons of buying 1,2,3 are independent from Reasons of buying A,B,D)

```
     Pearson's Chi-squared test
data:  df
X-squared = 7.3028, df = 4, p-value = 0.1207
```

While it is clear in the AFC that the reasons are not independant, why I don't have significant result of p-value on chi-square ? What is the problem in my analyses ?

Answer (score 2):

I see at least two problems with your approach: the data, and your interpretation of the correspondence analysis plot.

First, you shouldn't use a chi-square test like that with weighted data (NB: I assume that by "ponderating" you mean "applying weights"). It is unclear where the weights you used are coming from. You should provide more information about them -or better, ask a specific question about the validity of what you did exactly. For example, if they are some survey weights, a Rao-Scott chi-square test may be more appropriate than a "vanilla" chi-squared test. See also [Can chi-square test be used on non-integer observed frequencies?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/242990/can-chi-square-test-be-used-on-non-integer-observed-frequencies)

Secondly, the plot describes the sample, not the population. So you can't draw conclusions about the population just from it. Incidentally, when you run the line `CA(df)`, the FactoMineR package throws a message saying that the chi-squared test has a p-value of 0.12, certainly to remind you to interpret the plot with caution. So no contradiction here.

Correspondence analysis is chiefly a descriptive technique, not an inferential one (even though some extensions like [confidence ellipses](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/FactoMineR/versions/2.8/topics/ellipseCA) may allow some inference -yet I'm not sure how correspondence analysis and associated confidence ellipses would work with survey weights, or if it would even make sense).